# How to pass user entered value into custom hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I created a React custom hook named useApiRequest. I have a input component and the idea is that I want to pass the user input into the custom hook as parameter so that the custom hook fetch the data based on user input. But i can't find a way to do it without calling the custom hook inside a nested component.

Here's the custom hook code:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const useApiRequest = (url, query = '') => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true)
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url + query)
        setData(response.data)
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [url, query])

  return {data, loading, error}
}

export default useApiRequest
```

And here's the component where i use the custom hook

```
import SearchForm from "../UI/SearchForm"
import samplePrompt from "../../constants/text"
import Genre from "./Genre"
import { useState } from "react"
import useApiRequest from "../../hooks/use-api-request"

const Search = () => {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("")

    const {data, isLoading, error} = useApiRequest("some API link", searchQuery)

    const searchHandler = (newValue) => {
        setSearchQuery(newValue)
    }

    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div className="mx-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen w-full">
            <div className="text-center">
                <h1 className="text-5xl font-poppins font-bold mt-8">Cari Anime Berdasarkan Deskripsi menggunakan Kecerdasan Buatan</h1>
                <p className="mt-4">{samplePrompt[0].samplePrompt}</p>
            </div>
            <SearchForm searchQuery={searchQuery} onSearch={searchHandler} />
            <Genre />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

I'm sorry if I didn't explain it clearly. But I hope you get the idea.
Thank you

Comment: What is not working?